# Google Maps Flutter Directions

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, flutter-dependencies

Using google_maps_flutter package for maps. Configured my API and added Android Map SDK and Directions SDK. For getting polypoint route in perspective of the road.
"{

```
"error_message": "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address <MY-IP-ADDRESS>, with empty referer",

"routes": [],

"status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

}"

This is the response I am getting. Can anyone help me with this.

I tried in normal way with flutter_polyline_points package which did not work and also tried to get information from api link - "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
final response = await _dio.get(
_baseUrl,
queryParameters: {
'origin': '${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}',
'destination': '${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}',
'key': Variables.google_api_key
}
);
In response I get is what I have given above. Status is "status": "REQUEST_DENIED". What to do?

Comment: are you getting response in postman?

Comment: I used Polylinepoints to draw custom line. As i was unable to get through my way with Google Directions API.

Comment: It looks like you have set an IP restrictions in your cloud project that is not similar to the IP you using when generating requests. You should file a support case for a better line of support: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support. Please also avoid including your IP address in public sites as it is considered as PII.

Comment: Thanks @Yrll just removed the comment. Commented it by mistake. I didn't use google directions api. Rather used custom LatLong points in the map to draw polylines.

Comment: That's great to hear that you found a workaround. But incase you want to use Directions API again, I highly suggest you do what I commented above.

Comment: Yes, I surely have to work on that. If I can get it done will definitely post.